# un escaping css \3a using php

Tags: php, css, decode

i have a url that i am trying to parse within the facebook website which i've never come across, at first i thought it was just url encoded and a simple url decode would do. Then i tried string and replace which again didnt work. After some searching on line it appears to be css escaped string.

```
    https\3a //scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/c1.0.240
```

the issue is with the '\3a ' i cant work out how to convert it to its natural form a ':'

Comment: It would of been `%3A%20` but looks like its been lowercased and worked on (show that if you are), a simple str_replace would change it, but you should find out what the real issue is. Where is this link coming from?

Comment: i am parsing the html of a facebook profile page, and extracting the string which represents the users profile image. It looks like which i was doing the string and replace i wasn't then escaping properly when doing double quotes, its working now.